# What's the difference between particles と and も？

Tags: grammar, particles, word-usage

From what I understand, they both can mean "and" and "also" or something, but I don't entirely get the difference. Please try to explain in as simple of terms as possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first point to note is that the particles も and と have many different uses other than the ones you mentioned, so don't be surprised if you see them used in ways that don't fit this discussion.

When と is used to mean 'and' it denotes exhaustive listing. So if you say:

> 犬{いぬ}と猫{ねこ}がいる。

It means that there is a dog and a cat and nothing else. In contrast if you replace と with や it would mean that there is a dog and a cat and maybe some other animals that I haven't mentioned.

I can't think of any case in which と could be used to mean 'also'.

も can mean 'also'. For example:

> 私{わたし}も猫{ねこ}が好き{すき}
>   I like cats too. (I, in addition to someone else, like cats)
>   私{わたし}は猫{ねこ}も好き{すき}
>   I like cats too. (I like cats in addition to other animals)

も can mean 'and' if it appears more than once:

> 犬{いぬ}も猫{ねこ}もいる。
>   There are both cats and dogs.

Which is equivalent to "There are dogs and there are also cats", so it still has a meaning of 'also' as well as 'and' in this context.

Comment: I've seen this sentence: 書{か}くことも話{はな}すことも好{す}きです。Is も used because it would be strange having と just after こと ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong or strange about ことと. I'm not a native speaker so I'm not sure, but I don't think も~も has an exhaustive meaning like と. I think if you said 書くことと話すことが好きです, it would suggest that writing and speaking were the **only** things you liked. Whereas with the sentence you saw, there is no such implication. It might be worth asking a separate question about this.